# in django CreateView, how do I add field and send that field as a context to template?

Tags: python, django

I know this is very beginner question but I still don't get it even after I read https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/
so I have this createView right...

```
class PostCreateView(CreateView):

     model = Post
     form_class = PostForm
     template_name = 'main/add_post.html'

     def form_valid(self, form):

            self.object = form.save(commit=False)
            # any manual settings go here
            self.object.moderator = self.request.user
            self.object.image = extract(self.object.url) 
            self.object.thumbnail = extractt(self.object.content)
            self.object.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('post', args=[self.object.slug]))

     @method_decorator(login_required)
     def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(PostCreateView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

and in add_post.html I want to use

```
     hotCat = Category.objects.get_hotCat()
```

how do I use that hotCat in add_post.html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You add variables into the context by overriding the `get_context_data()` method.

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    ctx = super(PostCreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    ctx['hotCat'] = Category.objects.get_hotCat()
    return ctx
```

Comment: thank you, if I were to add one more field, then I should do onemore = super(PostCreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs) and onemore['regularCat']=Category.objects.get_regulartCat() and do return ctx, onemore??

Comment: No need to call super again, just  `ctx['regularCat'] = Category.objects.get_regulartCat()`.

Comment: Additionally, you should refer to your context variables in HTML with `{{variable_name}}`, and not directly.

Comment: @ChuckLoganLim what do you mean

Comment: @mikebraa, with Rod's code as reference, when you try to call the `hotCat` variable in your HTML file, do so via `{{hotCat}}`.